# Rails method about foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I want to delete a company, but there is not dependent: destroy in the model.
Is there an ActiveRecord method on Rails to know which tables are connected to a specific foreign key ?

Comment: What exactly is that you want to know? What rails assumes is the foreign key column for an assocation? That can be done with [reflect_on_association](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_association). If you want to know what foreign key constraints exist in your database you can do it by checking `schema.rb` or by querying Postgres `pg_indexes` view from PSQL (run it with `rails db`). https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-list-indexes/

Comment: Rails automatically adds a method for the association, so if a `Person` `has_one :company` then the company is just `person.company` it gives you the model that is connected to the foreign key `company_id`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [ActiveRecord::reflect_on_all_associations](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations) and [Array#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-reject) you can filter all `has_many` association without `:dependent` key

```
Company.
  reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).
  reject { |association| association.options[:dependent] }
```

To get table names you can use `plural_name` attribute

```
Company.
  reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).
  reject { |association| association.options[:dependent] }.
  map(&:plural_name)
```